# Regex find nested function defination with parameters

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have text input like this

input:

> function1( param1,param2, function2 (param1,function3(param1)),fun())

I want to parse out data like this:

> fun()
>
> function3(param1)
>
> function2(param1,function3(param1))
>
> function1( param1,param2, function2 (param1,function3(param1)),fun())

basically i need to find each individual function with parameters.

i tried using Regex `\w+\s?\(.*\)` but it is giving me only this

> function1( param1,param2, function2 (param1,function3(param1)),fun()).

Comment: Regex is not the best when dealing with multiple levels of nesting like this.  You might want to simply look at writing a parser or finding an existing one that handles this for you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133601/can-regular-expressions-be-used-to-match-nested-patterns

Comment: Recursively unwrap functions and parse them. `const unWrap = s => s.replace(/\w+?\(\s*/, '').replace(/\)\s*$/, '')`

Comment: Thanks, I think unwrapping is the only way to extract all the functions from the string.